# Dataframe mutation in function not being applied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

My functions are:

```
def missing (df):
    df.iloc[:,:] = df.fillna(0)
def drop_nan_columns(df):
    df = df.dropna(axis = 1. how ="all", inplace = True)
def test (df):
    missing(df)
    drop_nan_columns(df)
    return df
```

When I call the `test` function it seems to only call the first of the two predefined functions, instead of both.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't assign df in drop_nan_columns function. Just use it as follows:

```
def drop_nan_columns(df):
    df.dropna(axis=1, how="all", inplace=True)
```